# How to fix Error 'You Likely forgot to export your component from the file..etc' error in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am importing component from another file to implement it in App.js file, But Unfornatuley getting this error: https://ibb.co/41ynFGX

Here the code:https: 
(header.js file):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const Header = () => <Text> Hello Ahmed </Text>;


export default Header;
```

(App.js) code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header';

const App = () => (
    <View>

       <Header />

    </View>

);

export default App;
```

It works Well Here(https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed105/tenacious-coffee), But I am getting the error when running the app on my device using atom.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any problem in ur definition. What is the react and node version you are using?

Comment: Basically React Stateless function definition is supported on React.14 and above, any lower version may not support it.

Comment: @Rahul react-native-cli 2.0.1  and node: v11.13.0

Comment: Thank You Very Much, This is the problem, everything went well once I updated the version of React.

Comment: Cool Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has been solved As the problem Was not related to the code itself, The problem was related to React Version. 
As @Rahul said: "Basically React Stateless function definition is supported on React.14 and above, any lower version may not support it.

So I had updated React by this command: npm install react@latest 
and everything is going well now.

Answer (score 4):

Hey change your code to this it will work.

import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

```
export default Header = () => {
    return (
        <Text>
            Hello Ahmed
        </Text>
    );
};
```

Comment: Check if properly if you are trying to import it from correct location. Your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that:

> Check the render method of 'App'

So try to export App as a class component and put your code in its render method:

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/header';

export default class App extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I had Tried that but the same problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

You might get this error if you are using MapView from expo. 
so use: **react-native-maps**

```
npm install react-native-maps --save-exact

yarn add react-native-maps -E
```

and, `import MapView from 'react-native-maps';`